# Is wordpress intefering with my PHP script?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

To isolate a problem I'm having, I have a script which receives POST data, counts up to 50 with a time delay, and logs the results to a file. **I'm testing with Chrome Restful Client**.

When I had wordpress installed on my hosting, I was finding that a mysterious GET request was causing the script to startup about a minute into processing which meant for some reason that I wouldn't get a response back from the original POST request.

After I deleted wordpress, instead of logging the mysterious GET request I instead get the following error around the same time, about a minute into runtime. It still means i don't get a response back from my POST request after the script finishes (see my php after this error):

```
Status
500 Internal Server Error Show explanation Loading time: 45612
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Response headers 
Date: Tue, 10 Jun 2014 10:54:36 GMT 
Server: Apache 
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 webmaster@**** and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Here's my PHP script. Note, it used to log "misfire" after about a minute because it would receive a blank mysterious GET request. **After deleting wordpress, this no longer happens** instead I get the above error!

```
<?php
echo "SCRIPT HAS FINISHED!";

$q = $_POST['q'];

$req=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

writelog("IP Logged: ".$ip);
writelog("User agent: " . $agent);
writelog("Post data: " . $q);
writelog("Request method: " . $req);

if ($q==""){
  writelog ("MISFIRE!!!");
  die;
}

writelog("*** Error check started ***");

for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
     writelog ($i);
     sleep(rand(2,20)); 
}

 function writelog($towrite)
{
  $tdate=date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
  $file = 'log/testlog.txt';
  $current = $towrite." --- ".$tdate."\n";
  file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND);
} 
writelog("*** Error check ended ***");
?>
```

Could this maybe have something to do with a redirect or something? I remember when testing in restful client before uninstalling wordpress, it would say that it had a 301 redirect from ...errortest.php/ to ...errortest.php.

Comment: How about posting your .htaccess file and maybe your directory structure?

Comment: I have wordpress installed on my main domain (public_html), but I have a subdomain which also had wordpress on it which is where the script is. That's the wordpress I deleted.

It goes: public_html/subdomain/folder/script

Comment: My .htaccess file in public_html (which has the wordpress) is: 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your PHP script is timing out, have you set the max execution time? You may want to take a look at the set_time_limit() function in PHP.

Comment: The script continues to log counting up to 50 until the very end every time. If that's the case, it couldn't be timing out right?

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood, it shouldn't be timing out in that case. Are you able to post what your server log is logging about the error?

Comment: My logs in cpanel aren't showing any errors unfortunately.

Comment: I spoke to my hosting and it turns out it is infact a server error based on the time limit being exceeded. Strange the script still runs, but that error is returned because of this either way.